# Gulp connect gives me cannot GET/ with angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, browserify

I am trying to setup a simple boilerplate wth gulp, browserify,angular and node.js  However, I get error of`cannot GET`.

[image: Folder structure]

Here's boilerplate url on github https://github.com/kushalmahajan/angular_boilerplate.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `root` directory inside of your `connect` task to serve files  from `app/`.

```
gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: 'app',
        port: 4000 
    })
})
```